# What header files should I include to use the flock function?

Tags: c, function, header-files

What header files should I include to use the flock function in C?

Errors I get during compilation:

```
[Error] 'LOCK_EX' was not declared in this scope
[Error] 'LOCK_NB' was not declared in this scope
[Error] 'flock' was not declared in this scope
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd;
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Kullanım: %s dosya_adi\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("Dosya açma hatası");
        return 1;
    }
    if (flock(fd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) == -1) {
        perror("Dosya kilidi hatası");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Dosya kilitlendi\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A search engine is a fairly quick way to look things up like this: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html -- it says the header file right there, is your man page the same?

Comment: Maybe [`#include <sys/file.h>`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock)?

Comment: You specifically ask for C but have a mix of C and C++ headers, and the C++ tag. Which is it?

Comment: This is for Linux?  Because `flock()` is a Linux-only function.

Comment: I only want it for C language.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you want to:

```
#include <sys/file.h>
```